# How do I invoke another command withen a listener/event with Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So I want to invoke a command when the bot joins a guild. With the help of other StackOverflows, I have tried the following:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
        setup_cmd = self.bot.get_command('setup')
        await self.bot.invoke(setup_cmd)
```

One of the problems I suspect is that the invoke() method wants a ctx, and on_guild_join doesn't provide a Context object. At any rate, when I try that, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brian\.virtualenvs\ComBot-l9j8wB-A\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Documents\c0de_box\projects\Bots\ComBot\cogs\setup_tasks.py", line 14, in on_ready
    await self.bot.invoke(setup_cmd)
  File "C:\Users\brian\.virtualenvs\ComBot-l9j8wB-A\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 935, in invoke
    if ctx.command is not None:
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'command'
```

So how would I invoke another command in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bot.invoke` takes `Context` as the argument, not a `Command` instance, though it's not possible to get the `Context` in the `on_guild_join` event, you should make a function and call it in the command and the event

```py
async def setup_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
    await self.setup_func(...)

@commands.command()
async def setup(self, ctx, ...):
    await self.setup_func(...)
```

Comment: Well in the end I wasn't able to get what I wanted, so I just removed it as a command and attached it to the on_guild_join listener.